# Personal bookmarks

Tags: feature-request, user-profile-page

Is it possible to mark questions as personal bookmarks on my profile page?

A list of my own questions is displayed but I wonder how I can add other interesting questions I would like to remember!?

Comment: You could add to favorites with the star below the up- and downvoting arrows. Does this solve it for you?

Comment: Yes, partially. Partially because by starring a question I necessarily suggest to others that the question is interesting (which it might not be in general, thus producing a misleading bias in the "star rating"). I would think that starred questions should be only those which are of special general interest. Another point: It would be convenient to be able to mark particular answers. Example: I wanted to mark http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7877/16865 for later attention. though I would doubt that the original question of this thread is of major general interest.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't be concerned about the bias introduced by you starring a question. I rather interpret starring a question as being very valuable to a particular user, in this case you. And IMHO that is precisely what stars are for. But of course, anyone is free to disagree. `:)`

Comment: OK, convinced! Could you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in my comment(s), marking a question as a favorite, by clicking the star below the arrows for up- or downvoting is a solution. Later these can be listed by the user. This a good system to show at the same time that the question (or an answer to it) was particularly valuable for a user.